# Using Windows ren command to remove ! from filename

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a bunch of files that are in the following format

```
filename-!#.ext
```

where # is an incrementing number to prevent collisions. I would like to just remove the ! from the filename so it reads as

```
filename-#.ext
```

It seems like I could do this with the ren command and wildcards but having a hard time getting it to work. I tried running this:

```
ren *!?.ext *?.ext
```

My thought is the * should match the filename- part, then !, then the ? for the numeric. However, the resulting file is named this:

```
filename-!#.ext.ext
```

and I can't quite figure out why.

The filename part can be dynamic, but won't contain any !'s. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you'll have to resort to a small batch file for this:

```
@echo off
    setlocal
    for %%a in (*!*.ext) do call :remove "%%~a"
    goto :eof

:remove
    set "FROM=%~1"
    set "TO=%FROM:!=%"
    ren "%FROM%" "%TO%"
    goto :eof
```

The above will – for all files containing an exclamation mark and extension `ext` – call the `remove` function. This takes the original name (`FROM`) and determines the new name (`TO`) by using the `%var:find=replace%` syntax to remove any exclamation mark (replaces it with an empty string).

**Notes**

- You cannot use find/replace with either `%%a` or `%0` type variables, so you have to assign it to a named variable first.
- I originally tried doing this "inline" with the `for` statement (e.g. `for ... (` ending `)`) but to do that, you would have to enable delayed-expansion (because you would need to access a named variable in a loop). However, delayed-expansion uses `!` (instead of `%`) to reference variables and this got in the way of the `!` we were trying to remove. There may be a way of doing this, but I haven't found it. Using `call` will be slightly slower, but not significantly unless you've got thousands of files.
- You don't really need to create `TO` (you could perform the replacement on the `ren` command-line) but I used it for clarity.
- This will work for all files with an exclamation mark: it doesn't check the bit after is numeric.

Comment: good answer. I was trying to make a very short version using delayedExpansion to automatically remove the single ```!``` but when renaming, cmd ignored all ```"``` and "detected" a variable over the arguments, like ```ren "arg!var" "!arg2!"```. So I ended up with the inline-call-version which I would prefer in this case, because you don't need any external label to jump to (and you have less code).

Comment: @timlg07 Yes, I think I had the same problem. I'll have to try and remember your `call set` trick (I have seen it before, but obviously not often enough).

Comment: Also nice, but this also would double `^`-signs in the original file name; you could avoid that by not using argument `%~1` but assigning `set "FROM=%%~a"` in the `for` loop and reading variable `FROM` in the sub-routine...

Answer (score 5):

I think it is not a good idea to let `rename` select the files, but instead do it with a `for`-loop and then execute the rename for every file:

```
for %%F in (*!*) do (
    set "nxF=%%~nxF"
    call ren "%%nxF%%" "%%nxF:!=%%"
)
```

You really have to use `call` here instead of `delayedExpansion`, because `delayedExpansion` would destroy the rename-arguments (because they contain `!`)

Comment: You beat me to it.  But you can do this with one less `CALL`.  Just do the replacement and rename at the same time: `call ren "%%F" "%%newF:!=%%"`

Comment: yes, I forgot to shorten that at the end. Thank you ;)

Comment: Great answer, but there is one small problem: any `^` in the original file name would become doubled; to avoid that use another interim variable like `set "oldF=%%~fF"` and use `%%oldF%%` rather than `%%~fF` within `call`...

Comment: who puts ```^``` in a file name? ;D Thanks for the comment, I updated my code.

Answer (score 4):

Based upon your provided information and just for the sake of offering something a little different, you could let delayed expansion do the work for you, *(as it will remove the unwanted exclamation mark for you)*.!

```bat
@For %%A In ("*-!?.ext") Do @Set "_=%%A" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & Ren "!_!" "%%A" & EndLocal
```

---

You could probably also do it with a nested for loop:

```bat
@For %%A In ("*-!?.ext") Do @For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=!" %%B In ("%%A") Do @Ren "%%A" "%%B%%C"
```

…and from the Command Prompt:

```bat
For %A In ("*-!?.ext") Do @For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=!" %B In ("%A") Do @Ren "%A" "%B%C"
```

Comment: great solution, I was also planning to do this, but forgot to save the old file name ^^

Comment: Very nice! I think it's worth to mention that this relies on the fact that there is a single exclamation mark in each file name...